# Como saber qual imagem foi clicada em java

Tags: java, android

Tenho 4 imagens no meu layout, como saber qual foi clicada e fazer condicionais?
meu escript:

OnCreate:

```
ImageView bancada_tv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.main_bancada);
ImageView aguarda_tv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.main_aguarda);
ImageView pronto_tv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.main_pronto);
ImageView entregue_tv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.main_entregue);

bancada_tv.setOnClickListener(this);
aguarda_tv.setOnClickListener(this);
pronto_tv.setOnClickListener(this);
entregue_tv.setOnClickListener(this);
```

onClick:

```
@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

if(não sei como fazer){
}

}
```

Comment: Eu recomendaria usar o `id` da `View` como um diferenciador, mas há a possibilidade de usar `Listeners` anônimos.

Comment: Achei um jeito não sei se o mais correto mas pra mim ajudou. Usei o `v.getContentDescription();` e no xml em cada imagem atribuí um `android:contentDescription=""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só fazer assim:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if( v.getId() == R.id.main_bancada ) {
        // Faça algo para essa View;
    } else if( v.getId() == R.id.main_aguarda ) {
        // Faça algo para essa outra View;
    }

    // Ou então ao invés de usar if, utilize switch case
    switch( v.getId() ) {
        case R.id.main_bancada:
            // Chama algum método;
            break;
        case R.id.main_aguarda:
            // Chama algum método;
            break;
    }
}
```

Ou então utilize listeners anônimos com o @Walkim falou, ou então defina listeners diferentes para cada um deles. Você que sabe o jeito que irá fazer.